# What is the plan for the design of this website?

Tags: discussion, 7-essential, design

Are there any discussions going on about the UI, fonts, icons .. of this website?
**UPDATE:** If I came up with some concept, how do I show to the community for approval? Who approves the design?

Comment: you would show it to the community by posting it as an answer to this question

Comment: maybe as a link to DeviantArt or some other similar site?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be it.

However, it is still ***very*** early in the beta and I don't forsee this becoming an issue yet, but it is never too early to start.

Without any visual aids to help me.  I was thinking of something along the lines of film reels  in the background, movie canisters for the badges/background for [answered] questions, with a film noir color style (or even vibrant as with the early color days).  Ill try to work up a bit of a draft (I'ma crappy artist) in the next few days/weeks.

**EDIT**: The process seems to be initially done by SE's graphic designer with the site's community putting in input for the design for a few revisions.

[**Reference**](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/how-will-the-logo-and-design-be-chosen)

Comment: I'm editing my question to add an additional question. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: Edited this answer with a reference to what the process seems to be.

Comment: Please read this blog post: **[The 7 *Essential* Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)**. It's not too early to be having this discussion. It all a part of taking ownership of your site and not just waiting around until someone else gets to it.

Comment: Or what about clapperboards instead of reel canisters?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a recipe ingredient suggestion to me ;)

Anyways i think the logo of our site should be a clapperboards, which goes very well with both of our expects Movies and TV. Other suggestion should be  like :-

- Oscar as badges.
- Not too dark background, something like [academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).
- Open movie reel at the bottom.
- TV on the header part will complement our name
- Subtle color scheme.

Comment: I like these suggestion, except the oscar part, [the oscar statuette design is copyrighted](http://www.oscars.org/legal/regulations) and would probably be illegal to use without permission. It could be some other symol though, perhaps [stars like on the Hollywood walk of fame](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rHeEH.jpg)?